# How to prove that $\mathbb{Z/2Z\times Z/2Z}$ is not cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

How to prove that $\mathbb{Z/2Z\times Z/2Z}$ is not cyclic?

Here is what I did, what is wrong with it if anything and is there a better way to prove it?
A group $G$ is cyclic if $\exists\ a \in G$ such that $\forall g \in G, \exists\ k \in N$ such that $g=a^k$.

Here an element $g$ of $G=\mathbb{Z/2Z\times Z/2Z}$ writes $g=(x,y)$ with $x,y \in \{\bar{0},\bar{1}\}$, ie $g \in \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$

and there exists no $a \in G$ and $k,k',k'' \in N$ such that $a^k=(0,0), a^{k'}=(0,1)$ and $a^{k''}=(1,0)$

Comment: Should this question maybe be closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2225637/10513)? This makes sense given the dates, but this one is *slightly* more general ("not cyclic" versus "not cyclic of order $4$").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did was fine.

Another way would be to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not isomorph with $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Since the latter is the only cyclic group of order $4$ (up to isomorphism), the result follows.

To actually prove they are not isomorph, you can look at the orders of the elements of both groups.

Comment: Actually I wanted to show that $Z2×Z2$ was not cyclic to prove that it is not isomorph with $Z4$ which is cyclic. What do you mean by "To actually prove they are not isomorph, you can look at the orders of the elements of both groups."?

Comment: Isomorphisms preserve orders of elements. So, if one group has an element of order 4 and the other one doesn't they can't be isomorphic. But, a finite group is cyclic iff it contains an element with order the cardinality of the group, so checking that $Z_2 \times Z_2$ does not have an element of order $4$ is equivalent with that the group is not cyclic, and there is actually no need for an isomorphism argument.

Comment: Ok with the proof, thanks, but what element in $Z_4$ is of order 4? And: "a finite group is cyclic iff it contains an element with order the cardinality of the group, so checking that Z2×Z2 does not have an element of order 4 is equivalent with that the group is not cyclic" -> how comes $Z_2$ x $Z_2$ is of cardinal 4? I wrote that there were only 3 elements ($(0,0), (0,1),(1,0)$) so it should be of cardinal 3 right?

Comment: (1) Look at the element $1$ in $Z_4$. Then $1+1+1+1 = 0$, (2) You forgot $(1,1)$

Comment: (1) I don't understand. The identity $e$ is $1$ as $k*1=k\ \forall k$ and $g \in G$ (G of order $n$) is of order $k$ if $a^k \equiv e (\mod n)$. So 1 should be of order 0 as $1^0=1 \equiv e (\mod n)$ Why do you multiply 1 by 4? Where does that come from?

Comment: I see where your confusion comes from. You think of $Z_4$ as a multiplicative group, while it is an additive group. The operation is addition, not multiplication. This means, $* = +$ here. The identity for this additive group is $0$ btw, not $1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78997/discussion-between-astudentofmaths-and-math-qed).

Answer (score 8):

Because the group is so small, the easiest elementary way is probably finding the order of each nonzero element:

- $2\cdot(1,0) = (0,0)$
- $2\cdot(0,1) = (0,0)$
- $2\cdot(1,1) = (0,0)$

So we can conclude that every element has at most order $2$, so no element has order $4$, therefore no element generates the whole group, therefore the group is not cyclic.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why do you multiply by 2 each non-null element of $Z/2Z$  x $Z/2Z$? What does it imply that the product is 0 each time? To show that $a \in G$ is of order $2$ we must show that $a^2=e$ and $a^1 \neq e$, $a^0 \neq e$. I don't understand how it is related with what you wrote.

Comment: @astudentofmaths I used additive notation (as it is usually done with commutative groups), and showed exactly what you just wrote. But in the *additive* notation (in contrast to the *multiplicative notation* that you just used) the equation $a^2 = e$ becomes $2a = e = 0$.

Comment: A very simple change in your argument shows that $\mathbb{Z}/312465\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/312465\mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic.