# Intuitive definition of injective, surjective and bijective

Tags: functions

I tried to find a more intuitive way of explaining to myself how injective and surjective functions work. Does the following make sense? I'm assuming you have a function defined in the form $f(x)=y$.

1. Injective functions, for every unique $y$-value, have at **most** one corresponding $x$.
2. Surjective functions, for every unique $y$-value, have at **least** one corresponding $x$.
3. Bijective functions are both injective and surjective, so for every unique $y$-value, they have **exactly** one corresponding $x$.

Comment: I saw your title and I wanted to comment exactly your three points. So yeah, I think that's a pretty good explanation.

Comment: Yes, your statements make sense. This answer may help. It uses words with suffix "morphism" that you won't have encountered yet but you should be able to translate it into words about functions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039702/what-is-an-homomorphism-isomorphism-saying/2039715#2039715

Answer (score 2):

Here is another angle for injectivity:

- "$f:X \to Y$ is a function" is equivalent to "$x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$"
- "$f:X \to Y$ is injective" is equivalent to "$x_1=x_2 \impliedby f(x_1)=f(x_2)$"

Additionally, when counting the finite number of elements in sets $S$ and $R$, we have by pigeonhole principle:

- If $f:S \to R$ is injective, then $R$ has at least as many elements as $S$; $|S| \leq |R|$.
- If $f:S \to R$ is surjective, then $S$ has at least as many elements as $R$; $|S| \geq |R|$.
- If $f:S \to R$ is bijective, then $S$ and $R$ have exactly the same number of elements; $|S|=|R|$.

Also:

- Function: for each input there exists a unique output.
- Bijective function: for each output there exists a unique input (and vice versa!). Existence from surjectivity, uniqueness from injectivity. This gives a sense of why a bijection is sometimes called a "one-to-one correspondence."

Answer (score 0):

For the function
$$
f(x) = 2
$$
what is your $y$? The $2$ or else?

That is one reason why one provides the sets the function maps:
$$
f : X \to Y
$$
One characterization of a surjective function would be $f(X) = Y$.