# Clarifying the homomorphism's definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

So, I've heard a lot that homomorphism is a structure-preserving mapping between somewhat algebraic objects. Rigorous definition is: 
$f(x \circ y) = (f x) \circ (f y)$.
And it's not clear enough for me why operation from the left (denoted as $\circ$) **remains unchanged on the right**? Does it mean that homomorphism suppose to work only with algebraic objects sharing **the same** operation? Or this definition is just not enough explicit, shadowing the fact that $\circ$ gets mapped as well to a, let say, $\bullet$ and those are different in general?

Intuitively it feels like $f(x \circ y) = (f x) \bullet (f y)$ would be more correct.

Comment: you are right. An homomorphism preserves the same kind of operations between algebraic structures, but these operations are not the same generally.

Comment: Of course, the domain and codomain of the homomorphism *could* be the same object, in which case the the operations on the left and right side are the same - and then we call the homomorphism an endomorphism.

Comment: Related, possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039702/what-is-an-homomorphism-isomorphism-saying/2039715#2039715

Answer (score 19, accepted):

And your intuition is correct. Usually, the homomorphism is between two algebraic structures with distinct operations.

Answer (score 18):

*Does it mean that homomorphism suppose to work only with algebraic objects sharing the same operation?*

No. It means that, when working with algebraic objects, we usually share the same symbol for different operations.

[Herstein's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=6UzGQgAACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22I.+N.+Herstein%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9sN6ep-TZAhVIhpAKHdxZBVMQ6AEILDAB) (p. 67) explains this issue in the context of groups:

> **Definition.** Let $G, G'$ be two groups; then the mapping $\varphi:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism if $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for all $a, b\in G$.
>
> In this definition the product on the left side - in $\varphi (ab )$ - is that of $G$, while the product $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ is that of $G'$.

Analogously, for a general homomorphism $f(x \circ y) = (f x) \circ (f y)$, the symbol $\circ$ on the left stands for the operation in the domain, while the symbol $\circ$ on the right stands for the operation in the codomain.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you are right. Take, for instance, $A=B=\mathbb{R}$, and take the usual sum ($+$) on $A$ and the usual product ($\cdot$) on $B$. Then a homomorphism between the two structures $(A,+)$ and $(B,\cdot)$ is a function $f:A\longrightarrow B$ such that for each $x,y\in A$ we have
\begin{equation}
f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)
\end{equation}
An example of such function is the exponential, $f(x)=e^x$.

Answer (score 9):

The theory of your algebraic structure introduces a language for expressing calculations. For example, the theory of a ring introduces symbols $0,1,+,-,\cdot$, and we have a language using those symbols to express calculation.

Usually, we express things in this language unless there is a compelling reason not to do so.

Among the things ring homomorphisms must satisfy is requires $f(x \cdot y) = f(x) \cdot f(y)$. When you read that equation, you should read both instances of $\cdot$ as referring to the operation given in the theory of a ring; in *this* sense, both sides refer to the "same operation".

What's different about the two sides is the *interpretation* of the operation:

- In $f(x \cdot y)$, one *interprets* the operation in accordance with the domain of $f$
- In $f(x) \cdot f(y)$, one *interprets* the operation in accordance with the codomain of $f$

The (correct!) idea you are expressing is that these *interpretations* may be completely different functions between sets.

IF you were in a situation where you really did have cause to express arithmetic in terms of names for the specific functions that serve as the interpretations, then if the interpretation of $\cdot$ in the domain is a function we call $\circ$, and on the codomain is a function we call $\bullet$, then you would indeed translate $f(x \cdot y) = f(x) \cdot f(y)$ into the expression $f(x \circ y) = f(x) \bullet f(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. It's an abuse of notation. More formally, you should have something like the following.

Suppose $(G,\oplus_G)$ and $(H,\oplus_H)$ are groups. Then $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism if and only if $$f(x \oplus_G y ) =f(x) \oplus_H f(y)$$ for all $x,y\in G$.

The subscript is often dropped and inferred from context -- that's the "abuse".