# Why does "Hom" in a $\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{A}}(A, B)$ stand for "homomorphism"?

Tags: category-theory, definition

Not so long ago I asked [to clarify what is "homomorphism"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686244/clarifying-the-homomorphisms-definition) and had few nice answers. Now I am kind of reiterating what I've learned already about category theory, and accidentally found following:

> People also write $\mathsf{A}(A, B)$ as $\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{A}}(A, B)$. The notation **"Hom" stands for homomorphism**...

But when I get back to the definition of the $\mathsf{A}(A, B)$, it does not require morphism between objects $A$ and $B$ to be **structure-preserving maps**; more than that, it does not require morphism to be maps at all, those are just "arrows" and thus any attempt to define "structure-preservation" (without additional details of what kind of objects are, etc.) is senseless.

So I feel confusion, whether the answers I got from the question referenced above are incomplete, or where else am I missing the point? Maybe "homomorphism" has also some informal, historical meaning?

Comment: Yes, it's just a nod to algebraic origins.  Read it as "mor" if you need to.

Comment: @Randall: So... *In the midnight hour she cried Mor, Mor, Mor... With a rebel yell, Mor! Mor! Mor!* is the correct lyrics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ predates the invention of category theory.  In particular, for instance, it was used to denote the group of homomorphisms between two abelian groups $A$ and $B$.  So, when categories came along, and people wanted to talk about the set of morphisms between two objects in a general category, it was natural to extend this familiar notation to other settings.

Comment: But was rigorous homomorphism's definition known at that time?

Comment: @Sereja Bogolubov the notion of homomorphism is not any newer than the notion of abelian group.