# I'm learning ring theory but just wanted some more information as my notes are limited

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\theta : \mathbb{Z}_8 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ be defined by $\theta([i]_8) = [i]_4$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. You may assume that this is a well-defined ring homomorphism. Find $\mathrm{Ker}(\theta)$ and exhibit the partition of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ into cosets of $\mathrm{Ker}(\theta)$.

Can anyone please explain to me what $\mathrm{Image}(\theta)$ and $\mathrm{Kernel}(\theta)$ are. I have the definition and I understand the mapping but how is it used? Why is it relevant? I don't even know if these are the correct questions to ask.

Comment: It will be helpful if you let us know what $t$ is.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. To get help here you should edit your question so that it has the full context of what you are asking about. In this case there must be some ring and some $t$. Then tell us what you do understand, and where you are stuck. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: t is just theta in my notes. (I apologise in advance for my ignorance if this is not what you are asking!)

Comment: Whether it is $t$ or $\theta$, we still need to know what it is.  Is it a homomorphism of rings?  If so, between which two rings?  Perhaps you could share the definitions that you have?

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. I am a newbie to this.

Comment: Good edits to improve the question! Can you figure out which cosets in the domain map to the $0$ element of the codomain? Then you'll know the kernel. Find out which elements of the codomain are actually values of $\theta$ and you'll know the image.

Comment: @EthanBolker I found my cosets to be [0]_8 and [4]_8?

Comment: @BillWallis Thank you for the edits.

Comment: Right. So those two cosets make up the kernel (that's the definition of the kernel). Now find the cosets of the kernel in the domain ring to finish the answer. Then post all of this as an answer to your own question (that's allowed here).

Comment: @EthanBolker I believe that to be just [0]_8? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Good work on this exercise. You might find this somewhat philosophical answer helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039702/what-is-an-homomorphism-isomorphism-saying/2039715#2039715

Comment: Lovely analogy, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

How is it used? Why is it relevant? Why do we care about kernels and images, anyway?

When we look at algebraic maps, i.e., homomorphisms between groups, rings, modules, etc., we want to understand their *structure*. Why? Well, it's pretty much what there is to study. The image and kernel of a homomorphism tell you, respectively, how much of the target object is "covered" or "reached" by the map, and the kernel tells you how much of the source object is folded up in order to make it fit in that image.

In this case, the source object is the ring $\Bbb Z_8$, and the target object is the ring $\Bbb Z_4$. Since the target object is smaller, (only four elements, as opposed to eight), something from the original object will have to be folded together. Thus, if you're trying to find out which $x\in\Bbb Z_8$ satisfy $\theta(x)=b$ in $\Bbb Z_4$, then you'll expect to have multiple solutions (if you have any), because more than one element of the domain is mapped to the same place in the image. The number of multiple solutions you'll have is determined by the size of the kernel.

Whether you have any solutions at all depends on whether $b\in\operatorname{Im}(\theta)$. The image of a map is precisely the same as the "range" of a function, as we talk about it in elementary precalculus or calculus.

There's more than that, but hopefully that's enough motivation to keep you calculating these things. Finding the specific image and kernel in your case appears to be something you're well on your way to doing, so I'll not get in the way of that :)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I can sometimes answer a question but I find it 'uncomfortable' answering without understanding the 'why' behind it. That makes so much sense, appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

$\ker(\theta) = \{[i]_8 \in \mathbb{Z}_8 : \theta([i]_8) = [0]_4\}$

So, you have to calculate $\theta([i]_8)$ and analyze the element modulo $4$.

Doing that, we have: $\theta([i]_8) = [i]_4 = [0]_4$, but that happens iff $i = 4k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
But you know that the only elements in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ that are multiple of $4$ are $[4]_8$ and $[0]_8$, so, $\ker(\theta) = \{[0]_8,[4]_8\}$.

The image of $\theta$ is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ itself, because $\theta$ is surjective.

To see that, let $[i]_4 \in \mathbb{Z}_4$. Then $[i]_4 = \theta([i]_8)$.
Note that $[i]_4 = 0, 1, 2$ or $3$.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: You can also see that the image of $\theta$ is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ observing that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \subset \mathbb{Z}_8$, so the map $\theta$ is just a projection.

Comment: It's not entirely correct to say that $\Bbb Z_4\subset\Bbb Z_8$. Elements of the former are cosets of $4\Bbb Z$, and elements of the latter are cosets of $8\Bbb Z$. Indeed, there are embeddings of $\Bbb Z_4$ into $\Bbb Z_8$, but this map doesn't reverse either of them.

Comment: Ok, you're right, it's just that I usually imagine $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, but of course, their elements are different in the sense you said.