# Inverse of a ring isomorphism is also an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f:R \rightarrow S$ be an isomorphism of rings.

Let $g:S \rightarrow R$ be the inverse function of $f$.

Show that $g$ is also an isomorphism.

I know I can show and isomorphism by first showing $g$ is injective, surjective, and operation preserving. I am unclear on how to do that exactly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only problem here, assuming you already know the basic set theory stuff for inverse functions, is to show the inverse preserves the operations. So suppose $\;s,s'\in S\;$ . You must prove $\;g(ss')=g(s)g(s')\;,\;\;g(s+s')=g(s)+g(s')\;$ ...Use bijectivity of $\;f\;$ for this

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039702/what-is-an-homomorphism-isomorphism-saying/2039715#2039715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because $f$ is a bijection, there are $r,r' \in R$ such that $f(r)=s$ and $f(r')=s'$. 
So now ,

$g(ss')=g(f(r)f(r'))=g(f(rr'))=rr'=g(s)g(s')$

also

$g(s+s')=g(f(r)+f(r'))=g(f(r+r'))=r+r'=g(s)+g(s')$.

finally,

$g(1)=g(f(1))=1$

Hence, $g$ is a homomorphism and since inverse of a bijective function $f$ is bijective, $g$ is also a bijective hence an isomorphism.