# What exactly is $\phi(G)$ in a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm learning about group homomorphisms and I'm confused about what the $\phi$ transformation is exactly.

If we have some group homomorphism $\phi : G\rightarrow H$ what exactly does $\phi(G)$ mean?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Related, possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039702/what-is-an-homomorphism-isomorphism-saying/2039715#2039715

Comment: I found your analogy very useful. Thanks for the link and your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi(G)$ is the image of $G$ under the mapping $\phi$, i.e. the set of all $\phi(x)$ for $x \in G$.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(G)$ denotes the image of the group $G$. This is actually a purely set-theoretic definition. Given a map of sets $f:X\to Y$, $f(X)$ denotes the image of $f$. That is, $f(X)\subseteq Y$ is $\{y\in Y: y=f(x)\:\text{for some}\:x\in X\}$.

Comment: Great thank you so much for your detailed answer!