# Listing methods to prove that two rings are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, big-list, ring-isomorphism

Really, this question comes down to listing propeties that are preserved by ring isomorphisms. Off the top of my head, I can think of:

- cardinality of the ring
- commutativity
- the order of elements
- being a UFD, PID, field etc.

What else is there?

Comment: Related (essentially a duplicate) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039702/what-is-an-homomorphism-isomorphism-saying/2039715#2039715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Having a multiplicative identity (!)
- Being free, algebraically closed, real closed, Noetherian, Artinian, local, or (semi)simple
- Its characteristic, dimension (over the prime field, Krull, projective,
  injective, global), depth, transcendence degree (when applicable)
- Having **isomorphic** $R-Mod$s

Pretty much anything one can think of, in particular literally anything first-order expressible ("Isomorphic structures are a fortiori elementarily equivalent")

Comment: The last sentence is the best part of the answer.

Comment: +1: good answer, but you are using "first-order" in an unusually broad sense in your last line: properties like algebraically closed or Noetherian require quantification over sequences or subsets of elements and aren't expressible in the first-order language of the theory of rings.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm not, I'm using it in the only possible sense; I don't mean to suggest that all the stuff in the list would fall under such a case: it's just a side comment that adds something if one knows what it's about, and harmless if they don't

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification. It was just a bit surprising because only your first example is first-order.

Comment: aren't "being algebraically/real closed" and "having a given specific characteristic" also first-order expressible? (not finitely of course)